# Opening Lua Files in Interactive Mode

Tags: lua, interactive-mode, lua-loadfile

I am beginning to learn Lua on my own with basically no prior programming knowledge.  I understand the basics of types, functions, tables, etc.  But in following the Lua tuts at Lua.org, I'm currently on the "Modules Tutorial" and am having issues understanding the proper/easiest way to call a file made into interactive mode.

If I used Notepad++ or Scite to create a file, can someone please help me understand how to open said file using the proper nomenclature to open it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that your file is named `foo.lua`, then in the Lua interpreter (i.e, the interactive mode), use [`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadfile). Note that `loadfile` does not raise error, so it's better to use `assert` with it.

```
f = assert(loadfile("foo.lua"))
```

It will load the chunk in `foo.lua` into the function `f`. Note that this will only load the chunk, not run it. To run it, call the function:

```
f()
```

If you need to run it immediately, you can use [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile):

```
dofile("foo.lua")
```

Lua uses [`package.path`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path) as the search path which gets its default value from `LUA_PATH`. However, it's better to use proper relative path in practice.

Comment: A common idiom to do this in one step is `assert(loadfile("foo.lua"))()`; this loads and runs the file, and if loading didn't work, displays the error.

Comment: Thanks!  I performed both `loadfile` and `assert` methods within the interactive mode and was successful!  That clears that up.  At first I got an error but quickly realized that my root folder for all of my Lua files was not within the Lua 5.1 root folder.  A simple relocation of that file and everything ran perfectly!

Comment: Actually, I have another stupid question.

What if I need to open a file in another directory (outside of the Lua 5.1 root folder)?  If I was to run `assert(loadfile("foo.lua))()` and it was in a separate folder, how would the syntax change?

Again thank you for your help!

Comment: @ToxicFrog Right, it's better to use `assert` since `loadfile` doesn't raise error, and I'll update the answer. But again, `loadfile` will only load the file, not run it.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 Use a proper relative path will do, or see the updated answer.

Comment: You guys are great! Thank you so much for your help.  I understand fully now.